# Find out where the given numbers are located in the series of vector in R

Tags: r

I have three variables a1, a2 and a3.

```
a1 <- 1:10
a2 <- 11:20
a3 <- 21:30
```

then I have another variable called `my.numbers <- c(1, 20, 22,11)`

I want to find out where these numbers are located. So the result I want is:

```
1 in a1
20 in a2
22 in a3
11 in a2
```

Any suggestion on how it can be done easy way?

Comment: `L = mget(c("a1", "a2", "a3")); lapply(L, intersect, my.numbers)`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple `purrr::map` functions, you can work across the numbers, then within that, across the `a` vectors.

I'm making a list of the `a` vectors with `tibble::lst` because it sets the names of the list as the names of the variables going into it—convenient for something like this where it's the name of the list item that's important.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a_list <- lst(a1, a2, a3)

my.numbers %>%
  map_chr(function(num) {
    which_a <- map_lgl(a_list, ~(num %in% .))
    a_name <- names(a_list)[which_a]
    str_glue("{num} in {a_name}")
  })
#> [1] "1 in a1"  "20 in a2" "22 in a3" "11 in a2"
```

You could use `match` or another function after the `map_lgl` instead—I left it verbose to make it a little more clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

For the record here is how you can get out the exact result in the question.

```
a1 <- 1:10
a2 <- 11:20
a3 <- 21:30

L<-list("a1"=a1,"a2"=a2,"a3"=a3)
my.numbers <- c(1, 20, 22, 11)

func<-function(item){
    my.numbers[which(my.numbers %in% item)]
}

Fin<-lapply(L, func)

for(i in 1:length(Fin)){
Index<-unlist(Fin[i])
name<-paste("a",i, sep="")
    for(i in 1:length(Index)){
       print(paste(Index[i], "in", name))
    }
}

[1] "1 in a1"
[1] "20 in a2"
[1] "11 in a2"
[1] "22 in a3"
```